# Extending Doctrine EntityManager with EntityManagerDecorator leaves wrong reference in UnitOfWork

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I am trying to extend the `EntityManager` in Doctrine using the `EntityManagerDecorator` and have run into a problem with a reference to the base `EntityManager` in the `UnitOfWork` being passed to the `prePersist` event via the `$eventArgs`.

It looks like the `EntityManager` is passed to the `UnitOfWork` in the `EntityManager::__construct` when the `UnitOfWork` is created.

I thought a solution might be that I can override the default `UnitOfWork` in `MyEntityManagerDecorator::getUnitOfWork()` like:

```
public function getUnitOfWork()
{
    if ($this->unitOfWork === null) {
        $this->unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork($this);
    }

    return $this->unitOfWork;
}
```

However I noticed that the `UnitOfWork::__construct()` requires an `EntityManager` not an `EntityManagerInterface` so this would not work.

I am looking for how I can get `MyEntityManagerDecorator` from the prePersist `$eventArgs->getEntityManager()` instead of the base `EntityManager`. I would like to do this **without directly inheriting** the `EntityManager`. The docs also say *"You should never attempt to inherit from the EntityManager: Inheritance is not a valid extension point for the EntityManager."*.

I am not sure what you require for code samples, if any, so please let me know if you require more information. I have access to `MyEntityManagerDecorator` as expected everywhere else in the project (that I have tried so far). I setup the decorator in `yml` like so:

```
my_multi_tenant_entity_manager:
    public: false
    class: My\MultiTenantBundle\ORM\MyEntityManagerDecorator
    decorates: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    arguments: [ "@my_multi_tenant_entity_manager.inner" ]
```

Here is a list of packages and version numbers I am using dumped from composer:

```
installed:
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.3             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.4.0             Caching library offering...
doctrine/collections                 v1.2               Collections Abstraction ...
doctrine/common                      v2.4.2             Common Library for Doctr...
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.1             Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             v1.3.0             Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       v1.0.1             Symfony2 Bundle for Doct...
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle  dev-master 6a1bd73 Symfony DoctrineMigratio...
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1             Common String Manipulati...
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.4              A small, lightweight uti...
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1             Base library for a lexer...
doctrine/migrations                  dev-master 058a463 Database Schema migratio...
doctrine/orm                         v2.4.7             Object-Relational-Mapper...
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler v2.1.0             Composer script handling...
jdorn/sql-formatter                  v1.2.17            a PHP SQL highlighting l...
kriswallsmith/assetic                v1.2.1             Asset Management for PHP
monolog/monolog                      1.12.0             Sends your logs to files...
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock    2.0.4              
phpspec/prophecy                     v1.3.1             Highly opinionated mocki...
phpunit/php-code-coverage            2.0.15             Library that provides co...
phpunit/php-file-iterator            1.3.4              FilterIterator implement...
phpunit/php-text-template            1.2.0              Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                    1.0.5              Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream             1.4.0              Wrapper around PHP's tok...
phpunit/phpunit                      4.5.0              The PHP Unit Testing fra...
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects         2.3.0              Mock Object library for ...
psr/log                              1.0.0              Common interface for log...
raven/raven                          dev-master 407d770 A PHP client for Sentry ...
sebastian/comparator                 1.1.1              Provides the functionali...
sebastian/diff                       1.2.0              Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                1.2.1              Provides functionality t...
sebastian/exporter                   1.2.0              Provides the functionali...
sebastian/global-state               1.0.0              Snapshotting of global s...
sebastian/recursion-context          1.0.0              Provides functionality t...
sebastian/version                    1.0.4              Library that helps with ...
sensio/distribution-bundle           v3.0.16            Base bundle for Symfony ...
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v3.0.4             This bundle provides a w...
sensio/generator-bundle              v2.5.2             This bundle generates co...
sensiolabs/security-checker          v2.0.1             A security checker for y...
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v5.3.1             Swiftmailer, free featur...
symfony/assetic-bundle               v2.6.1             Integrates Assetic into ...
symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.7.1             Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.3.8             Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                      v2.6.4             The Symfony PHP framework
twig/extensions                      v1.2.0             Common additional featur...
twig/twig                            v1.18.0            Twig, the flexible, fast...
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am attaching a Tenant object to the EntityManager to handle filtering records in the database. on prePersist I call $entity->setTenant($em->getTenant()); Then I have a query filter setup and a kernel request event that loads the tenant from the request. It is all working except I can not get the prePersist working due to the wrong entity manager being passed.

Comment: If there is a better way to accomplish this I would be appreciative of some suggestions. I thought this method seemed to make most sense because the EntityManager is mapping records for a specific Tenant. Whenever I need to map records the EntityManager is present so it seemed like the place to store my tenant information.

Comment: are you currently "extending" or "decorating" the `EntityMangager`?

Comment: hmm... not quite sure - the `getUnitOfWork()` snippet tells me otherwise. i'm going to outline a possible solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to decorate (and not directly extend) the `EntityManager`, as it looses the coupling between your implementation and the inherited component.

In order to be able to distinguish entities that do have a relationship to a tenant implement/extend those classes from an `interface` or a `mapped superclass`.

The securityContext (for demonstration purpose) is there to get the reference to the tenant.

```
/**
 * `EntityManagerDecorator` exists since v2.4
 */
class MultiTenantEntityManager extends EntityManagerDecorator {

    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $securityContext) {
        parent::__construct($entityManager);
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function persist($entity) {
        // set the tenant before persisting an entity
        if ($entity instanceof MultiTenantEntity) {
            $userId = $this->securityContext->getUserId();
            $tenant = $this->wrapped->find($userId,...);
            $entity->setTenant($tenant);
        }
        return $this->wrapped->persist($entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I am doing. The problem is that the UnitOfWork takes its entity manager from the construct of the EntityManager and will not except an EntityManagerInterface (allowing me to pass my decorator). I think I can move my events into the persist in the decorator instead though. That might work but then I still have the problem where I can not use any doctrine live cycle events as it provides the wrong entityManager (i.e. not my decorator)

Comment: I see that the `UnitOfWork` constructor depends on the `EntityManager` (and not the interface) - this is not ideal. But then again - why would you need to create your own `UnitOfWork` instance? If you need you could use `new UnitOfWork($this->wrapped)`. If you rely on the `EntityManagerDecorator` you would automatically delegate to the underlying (decorated) `EntityManager` and everything should work...

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was thinking, however `new UnitOfWork($this->wrapped)` still will pass the `EntityManager` in the doctrine lifecycle callbacks instead of the `EntityManagerDecorator`. I was thinking of overriding the `EntityManager::persist` in the decorator instead of using lifecycle callbacks but persist is not in the `EntityManagerDecorator` or the `EntityManagerInterface`. Is this omited for a reason? Is it safe to override this in a decorator?

Comment: `persist` exists in the `EntityManagerInterface` because it extends the `ObjectManager` (which declares `persist($entity)` -> see https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager.php and https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManagerInterface.php). So look at the example in the answer above - and let the `wrapped` entity manager instance do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Ah right, thanks, I must have missed that when I checked. So I will try that for now to get things moving. That still does not fix that I don't have the EntityManagerDecorator inside the UnitOfWork though.

Comment: I was wrong. The `UnitOfWork` constructor expects an `EntityManagerInterface`. So whatever you try to achieve - that should work.

Comment: It does not take an interface in the version I am using. Must have been fixed since. I might take a look at updating versions. For now I just moved what I needed into the Persist of the Decorator and it seems to be working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't put this in the $em but rather a listener for the persist event. And you can easily inject the security context in it.